# How many arguments does this function apply to?

Tags: arguments, racket

```
((lambda (x y) (* x y)) (2 3))

application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 2
  arguments...:
   3
  context...:
   /Applications/Racket v7.0/share/pkgs/sandbox-lib/racket/sandbox.rkt:493:0: call-with-custodian-shutdown
   /Applications/Racket v7.0/collects/racket/private/more-scheme.rkt:148:2: call-with-break-parameterization
   .../more-scheme.rkt:261:28
   /Applications/Racket v7.0/share/pkgs/sandbox-lib/racket/sandbox.rkt:861:5: loop
```

The correct expression should be

```
((lambda (x y) (* x y)) 2 3)
```

But I still don't quite understand the error message.

```
Given 2
```

indicates that the function expects 2 arguments, isn't it?
But what does the following means?

```
arguments...:
   3
```

I think the function takes `(2 3)` as one argument. Why it tells 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you’re seeing is *not* an arity mismatch error. When you apply a function with the wrong number of arguments in Racket, you get an error like this one:

```
> (define (f x)
    (void))
> (f 1 2)
f: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 2
  arguments...:
   1
   2
```

Note that the error message mentions the function name, in this case `f`, and it explicitly says “arity mismatch” and includes an explanatory description. The error message in your question is a different one:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 2
  arguments...:
   3
```

Let’s break this message down.

1. The error message does not mention any specific function name. Instead, the party signaling this error message is simply “application”, which is to say that the part of the language that implements function application is itself raising an error.
2. The short description of the error message is “not a procedure”. This means that you tried to apply some value as a function, but it wasn’t a function at all. The longer description elaborates on this: it expected a function that can be applied, but it found something else.
3. Given the above context, the “given” part of the error message makes more sense. The `2` in the message does not describe some number of arguments, but actually refers to the *value* that you attempted to apply. You can reproduce this with a slightly reduced example:

   ```
   > (2 3)
   application: not a procedure;
    expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
     given: 2
     arguments...:
      3
   ```

   It’s even clearer if we use an example that doesn’t involve numbers so that the values can’t be confused for something else:

   ```
   > ("not a function" "first arg" "second arg")
   application: not a procedure;
    expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
     given: "not a function"
     arguments...:
      "first arg"
      "second arg"
   ```

If we return to your original program, it becomes clear what went wrong. Due to the set of parentheses around `(2 3)`, you attempt to apply `2` as a function (since parentheses mean function application in Racket), which is not legal. The error reports this violation.